# iTunes movie classification

Tags: itunes, mp4

I have a few .mp4 files that I have added to iTunes.
Some are classified as Home Movies and other are My Movies.
I was wondering if there is any way to change this maybe by converting to a certain file type. I was also wondering how does iTunes determine this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use [Subler](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler), which allows auto & manual metadata & poster art tagging as well as muxing/remuxing of any of a video file’s subtitle, audio, chapter or closed caption tracks. It’s very light weight & I prefer it to all the other video taggers I’ve tried. You can change the ‘type’ of file from home video to movie very easily as well as set HD and other tags. Any changes made to a file already appearing in your iTunes library should be automatically revealed when you either click it to reveal the cast & synopsis information or with Get Info; in other words, you do not need to remove the file & reimport it, as the changes will be recognized in place. Just make sure you go up to the File menu item & hit Save.

Comment: I haven't found that using either Subler or MetaZ on files already in iTunes consistently parses the metadata without re-importing the file.

Comment: That’s strange. Subler has worked perfectly for me without any reimporting necessary on over 430 films and 12 complete tv series...

Comment: May just be a case of YMMV: Subler, MetaX and MetaZ all passed at least some, but not all, of the metadata to the movies in my iTunes library. Re-importing fixed it.

Comment: Which fields do they skip for you unless you reimport? Maybe that's the difference in our experiences.

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, Get Info on the specific video. From the Options tab, select Media Kind and change it to Movie or the appropriate format.

iTunes selects the Media Kind based on any metadata it can parse from the file. Lacking anything for .mp4 files, it defaults them to Home Video.

If you have movies ripped from DVD and want to add metadata, take a look at [MetaZ](http://griff.github.io/metaz/). (It's the replacement for the old MetaX when that stopped being updated and functionality broke.) iTunes properly reads the metadata that MetaZ embeds. You will want to remove the files from iTunes, process with MetaZ and then re-import them into iTunes.